# Modify JSON with typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am creating a Angular 2 application. My server side request returns me a JSON that will look like

```
[{"CountryId":1,"CountryCode":"IND","CountryName":"India","State":[]},
 {"CountryId":2,"CountryCode":"AUS","CountryName":"Australia","State":[]}]
```

I need to display this in a dropdown. So I need to create a new JSON that will look like

```
[{"Label":"India","Value":"IND"},
{"Label":"Australia","Value":"AUS"}]
```

I dont want to write for loop as i will be using this in many places and i want it to be best possible in performance. Please let me know if there is any inbuilt function that can do this kind of JSON restructure.

Comment: Are you sure you need to transform the JSON? Cannot the UI component be configured to use alternate keys for label and value?

Comment: A `for` loop is exactly what you need (although `map()` is nicer).

Comment: @Thilo I am using custom library [primeng](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown). This probably does not support for now.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to write some code darnit!

Comment: You don't really want to create new JSON.  I assume you're converting the JSON resturned to a javascript *array* and want to convert the *objects* in the array to objects with different properties.  Using JSON in your title and using the JSON tag makes it seem like you are talking about JSON in particular (JavaScript Object Notation), the string representation of javascript objects.

Comment: *This probably does not support for now* What probably does not support what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you know exactly how many elements there will be in your response array you can't escape from iterating it, although you can choose how:

```js
// A
let result = response.map((elem) => ({
  'Label': elem.CountryName,
  'Value': elem.CountryCode
}))


// B
let result = []

response.forEach((elem) =>
  result.push({
    'Label': elem.CountryName,
    'Value': elem.CountryCode
  })
)


// C
let result = []

for (i in response) {
  result.push({
    'Label': response[i]['CountryName'],
    'Value': response[i]['CountryCode']
  })
)
```

Comment: ... and it is very unlikely that any of this will cause any performance issues.

Comment: Yeap, don't worry, not with such a simple structure

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me give this a try.

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6 destructuring, the most compact form would be:

```
 response.map(({CountryCode: Label, CountryName: Value}) => ({Label, Value}))
```